# Open activity in the same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I try to open the same class as the one I am currently in with different parameters when pressing a button. I do this with:

```
Intent j = new Intent("com.test.com.ANSWER");
            id = calculateId(0);
            j.putExtra("id", Long.toString(id));
            startActivityForResult(j, 0);
```

But I get a nullpointer exception.. Is there some rule that you cannot open the same activity within itself?

**Error:**

```
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.Answer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at com.test.Answer.onCreate(Answer.java:86)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 01:29:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(2194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a rule about that but I'm also not sure it's a good idea. If that's what you need to do then maybe there should be a class that you subclass. Where's the null pointer exception at? It may have to do with something else like your calculateId() or somewhere else. Can you post logcat?

Comment: I added the error message! Ps, it is not the idea because if I change it to 1 for example, I still get that message..

Comment: What is at line 86 of onCreate and what does your calculate method look like?

Comment: Why are you starting the same activity for result? Maybe consider using fragments if you need to cycle through different UI patterns  within an activity

Comment: line 86 gets a value from an instance and the method is private long calculateId(int action) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if (action == 0) {
   if (id == 1) {
    id = itemsPerLevel;
   } else {
    id = id - 1;

   }
  } else if (action == 1) {
   if (id == itemsPerLevel) {
    id = 1;
   } else {
    id = id + 1;
   }
  }

  return id;
 }
I have the feeling that a variable is not correctly pushed forward with the new activity, will try to put all manually and drop the methods

Comment: How does it get the value? And is 'id' visible to that function and is it ever initialized?

Comment: I don't think the right value of id is getting there, answering your question i see that it needed the player name and level as a String.. i changed that to an int and now it does the trick! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your id isn't getting initialized. You are trying to initialize it with a function that uses the id so it never has a value. If this isn't it then you are using the same variable name in different places which isn't very good practice usually